# Jersey filter happens before Jetty url rewrite handler

Tags: java, jersey, swagger, jetty

I'm using Jetty rewrite handler to rewrite url like /recommendation/api/movies to /movies.

```
protected static JettyServerCustomizer jettyRewriteHandlerCustomizer() {
        return server -> {
            RewriteHandler rewrite = new RewriteHandler();
            rewrite.setRewriteRequestURI(true);
            rewrite.setRewritePathInfo(false);
            rewrite.setOriginalPathAttribute("originalPath");

            RewritePatternRule recommendationApiToNone = new RewritePatternRule();
            recommendationApiToNone.setPattern("/recommendation/api/*");
            recommendationApiToNone.setReplacement("/");
            rewrite.addRule(recommendationApiToNone);

            server.insertHandler(rewrite);
        };
    }
```

And I also configured Jersey as filter in order to serve swagger static content, like index.html.

```
spring.jersey.type=filter
```

However, in this way, it seems the request will hit the jersey filter first without being rewritten, which caused 404 resource not found.

Is there any way to make the rewrite handler come before the Jersey filter?

Answer (score 2):

My bad. I included the dependency spring-boot-starter-web without excluding the default tomcat server in it. So the jetty server didn't get started and couldn't rewrite the URL. Resolved.